# Word for popular conception of a period of history

Tags: single-word-requests, history

Recently, I listened to the [Heroes and Legends course](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/heroes-and-legends-the-most-influential-characters-of-literature.html) from **The Great Courses**. At one point, the author said a word which he defined as something along the lines of "Popular (and often exaggerated) conception of a historical period". I *think* he specifically mentioned the old west and said that it really only lasted about a lifetime (but he might have mentioned Medieval Europe, too). I don't remember the word he used, however. What is it?

Comment: Perhaps he talked about its *mythology*? We usually say something is a "mythologized" version of events. Cf. *hagiography*.

Comment: Seems like going back to the place he used that word would be a simple solution :-), but **idealization** seems quite possible.

Comment: _Tall tale_? They are usually exaggerated stories of familiar settings like the Old West.

Comment: I'm thinking I've heard such a word, but it's not coming to me.  "Saga" is about the best I can come up with.

Comment: There is, of course, "myth" and "fable", and, a bit more high-brow, "mythos".

Comment: @ScotM The lecture series is 12 hours long and I wasn't sure of where he first used it. I actually was able to take an extremely lucky guess and find the spot, but it took a half hour to find.

Comment: @Robusto: (and HotLicks) I like that. The one-word replacement adjective for "Imaginary" (which, I realize, was not asked for in the original question but was stated later) would be "mythical", as in "the mythical Old West"

Answer (score 1):

Listening to the relevant lecture again, the term he uses is "imaginary", but contextually it qualifies as jargon for literary criticism. He is not using it as an adjective, however, but as a noun. There is a "Wild West imaginary" and a "Medieval imaginary."

Comment: Here's to lucky guesses! It seems like an appropriate specialized use of *imaginary*.

Comment: @ScotM It was a heck of a guess: I have no way of telling what chapter I'm listening to at when listening in iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *the **romanticisation** of the Old West*.

A [Guardian chat article](https://profile.theguardian.com/user/id/4231640) includes;

> The hard core love of guns came with the romanticisation of the "Old
>   West" which was more legend and hype than fact.

Answer (score 0):

The two words that come to mind for history are:

***[legend](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/legend)***:

> NOUN
>
> 1 A traditional story sometimes popularly regarded as historical but
>   not authenticated:

and

***[idealization](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idealize?q=idealization#idealize__19)*** from idealize:

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT] (often as adjective idealized)
>
> Regard or represent as perfect or better than in reality:

Comment: The problem, though, is that this includes things which are often anything *but* an idealization: such things include the idea that Puritans, who were actually comparably permissive about sexuality, were more fastidious than the Victorians.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/conception?s=t